# Is there any callback on permission change for web push notification?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

Let say a user set permission to **allow** for receiving push notification but later changed those permissions to **denied** or **default** .

Is there some callback for this exposed in Serviceworker.

Answer (score 13):

There's no event that's exposed to the service worker.

There's an event that you could listen for from the context of pages, via the [Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API):

```
navigator.permissions.query({name: 'notifications'}).then(function(permission) {  
  // Initial status is available at permission.state

  permission.onchange = function() {  
    // Whenever there's a change, updated status is available at this.state
  };
});
```

Comment: I believe that is the correct answer, but it being experimental technology according to MDN, it's not yet supported by Safari: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.permissions.query')

Comment: Should I write this on self.addEventListener('activate',() => {}) on SW?